# Can the text in a HTML Select be different that what is in the 'drop down' that the user selects from?

Tags: jquery, html, select

When a user clicks on a Select, I want them to see the full state names in the 'drop down' like this.

```
<select name="address_region" id="address_region">
    <option value=1>Alabama</option>                    
    <option value=2>Alaska</option>                    
    <option value=3>Arizona</option>                    
    <option value=4>Arkansas</option>                    
    <option value=5>California</option>                    
    <option value=6>Colorado</option>                    
    ......
</select>
```

However, once the selection has been made, and the 'drop down' collapses, I want the text shown to be the abbreviation. (Eg: AL, AK, AZ, CA, CO etc.)

I tried adding an onChange event handler to the above select like this to test, but it fails:

```
function setRegionAbbreviation() {
    $('#address_region').text('AL');
};
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is slightly different that David's implementation — I have chosen to store the original text values in HTML5 `data-` attributes, which allows us to revert back to the full text when the option becomes unselected. After that, we bind the `.change()` event to the `<select>` element. When the option is selected, it's text value is overwritten by the value specified in `data-abbr`. If unselected, it will read the original value stored in `data-text`.

There are, of course, other ways you want to store the state name abbreviations: it can be in a JSON file, a JS object or array, which you can then choose not to use the `data` attribute instead.

The updated HTML:

```
<select name="address_region" id="address_region">
    <option value="1" data-abbr="AL">Alabama</option>                    
    <option value="2" data-abbr="AK">Alaska</option>                    
    <option value="3" data-abbr="AR">Arizona</option>                    
    <option value="4" data-abbr="AZ">Arkansas</option>                    
    <option value="5" data-abbr="CA">California</option>                    
    <option value="6" data-abbr="CO">Colorado</option>                    
</select>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$('#address_region')
// Find all <option> elements, and store their original text in a jQuery data object
.find('option').each(function() {
    $(this).data('text', $(this).text());
})
.end()
// End to return $('#address_region'), and bind change event
.change(function() {
    var $selOpt = $(this).find('option:selected');

    $selOpt
    // Replace text with abbreviation
    .text($selOpt.attr('data-abbr'))
    // For its siblings, revert to original text
    .siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
    });
});
```

Proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Djns9/

Comment: Works perfect. I am accepting your answer, because it fits easily with the code I have with no need for a separate array like David's. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
var stateAbbreviations = {
    'alabama' : 'AL',
    'alaska' : 'AK',
    'arizona' : 'AZ',
    'california' : 'CA',
    'colorado' : 'CO'
};

$('#address_region option').text(function(i, t) {
    return stateAbbreviations[t.toLowerCase()] || t;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LpGTz/2/).

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one

http://jsfiddle.net/MUFL7/

```
var prevOption;
abbr = function () {
    console.log('onchange');
    if(prevOption)
    prevOption.text = prevOption.getAttribute('data-expansion');
    var e = document.getElementById("address_region");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    e.options[e.selectedIndex].text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-abbr');
    if (!e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-expansion'))
        e.options[e.selectedIndex].setAttribute('data-expansion', strUser);
    prevOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
};

reset = function () {
    console.log('onclick');
    var e = document.getElementById("address_region");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    e.options[e.selectedIndex].text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-expansion') || strUser;
};
```

---

```
<select name="address_region" id="address_region" onchange="abbr()" onfocus="reset()">
    <option value=1 data-abbr="AM">Alabama</option>                    
    <option value=2 data-abbr="AL">Alaska</option>                    
    <option value=3 data-abbr="AZ">Arizona</option>                    
    <option value=4 data-abbr="AR">Arkansas</option>                    
    <option value=5 data-abbr="CA">California</option>                    
    <option value=6 data-abbr="CO">Colorado</option>                    
</select>
```